# Injecting controllers as a service in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

I have a controller, that isn't reachable from a route for special tasks. 
This controller is used by many routes to do these tasks.

At the moment I use `controllerFor()` to get it.

But since it is used as a service from other controllers I want to add it to every route with DI.

I tried the following in `Em.Application.initializer`

```
app.register('workspaceRTC:workspace', App.WorkspaceController);
app.inject('route', 'workspace', 'workspaceRTC:workspace');
```

Which didn't work.

**How do I correctly inject controllers in Ember.js?**

Comment: What didn't work?  And Is there a reason this needs to be a controller?  Why not just use an ember object and inject it both into your controllers and routes?  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gazexiquki/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: And here's an example with an object http://emberjs.jsbin.com/guzehakuwa/1/edit

Comment: How do I get the ember-data store in an object? It's not injected there.